# XML serialization number generation

Tags: xml, serialization, random

I'm making a text based game at present.

I want my XML to be in this sort of structure:

```
<North>
  <1>  </1>
  <2>  </2>
  <3>  </3>
  <4>  </4>
</North>


<NorthChoice>
  <1.1>   </1.1>
  <1.2>   </1.2>
  <1.3>   </1.3>
  <2.1>   </2.1>
  <2.2>   </2.2>
</NorthChoice>
```

So basically, "North" holds text which will influence the player's decision. Say the user selects on "1" then, data held in "NorthChoice" / "1.1" will be loaded.

How would I create a generator to generate all of these "1.1" etc?

Comment: [As a side note, that is not valid XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar). Tag names cannot start with a number, so you may get into trouble parsing the format with an XML parser.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: I've withdrawn my comment.

Comment: You haven't said how you are generating the XML. By hand? from a data set? from an algorithm. I would also comment that XML tags which different in indexes (<tag1.2>, <tag1.3> etc are probably not a good idea. Note that you can rely on the order of the tags. My own approach would be to use unique ID attributes <tag id="id1.1"/> ...

Comment: Forgot about that rule, thank you. 

Generating the XML through the user of an "IntermediateSerializer".